# Jenkins xvnc, HOME variable not set error

Tags: jenkins, vnc-server

Trying to get some jobs working that require xvnc, but get this:

```
  Starting xvnc
  [workspace] $ vncserver :14
  vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set.
```

I have no problems with running vncserver from the jenkins user on command line. (aside: 'printenv' shows the HOME variable is populated correctly when on the command line, but not from within a jenkins job).

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I don't usually run jenkins (because it launches automatically, with upstart I believe), but when I do, I use: "start jenkins". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into: /etc/init/jenkins.conf

Add the following line to the bottom of the env list.

```
env HOME="/var/lib/jenkins"
```

restart jenkins, enable the xvnc in your build, and then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit  `/etc/init.d/jenkins` on the server to set `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that...but wasn't super familiar with the upstart job aspect of it.  Should I just do 'export HOME=/var/lib/jenkins' right at the very start?

Comment: Here is [an example](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsLinuxStartupScript)

Comment: take back, that does not do the trick.  The script in question is 'old', and doesn't use upstart. :(

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with upstart, but it looks that you've got the idea - find the configuration file and set the variable in it.